# Why my code is printing last values retrieved from file instead of new one

Tags: c, fopen, file-read

I have the following code for reading files in C. It's reading from files but not like its supposed to be. It is showing up like this:

[image: current output]

instead of like this:

[image: correct output]

Although I am calling the same print function. We are taking records for 4 employees. I know it's a logical error but I am unable to solve it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct employee {
    float hoursWorked, hourlyRate, federalTax, stateTax;
    char name[20];
};

struct calc
{
    float grosspay, fto, sto, np;

};

void print(struct employee s[], struct calc c[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s's gross pay: $%.02f\n", s[i].name, c[i].grosspay);
        printf("Federal tax owed: $%.02f\n", c[i].fto);
        printf("State tax owed: $%.02f\n", c[i].sto);
        printf("Net pay: $%.02f \n\n", c[i].np);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void savetext(struct employee s[], struct calc c[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", s[i].name);
        fprintf(f, "%f %f %f %f\n", s[i].hoursWorked, s[i].hourlyRate, s[i].federalTax, s[i].stateTax);
        fprintf(f, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", c[i].grosspay, c[i].fto, c[i].sto, c[i].np);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void retrievetext(struct employee s[], struct calc c[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    int length;
    f = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fgets(s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name), f);
        length = (int)strlen(s[i].name);
        s[i].name[length - 1] = '\0';
        fscanf(f, "%f %f %f %f\n", &s[i].hoursWorked, &s[i].hourlyRate, &s[i].federalTax, &s[i].stateTax);
        fscanf(f, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", &c[i].grosspay, &c[i].fto, &c[i].sto, &c[i].np);

    }
    fclose(f);
}

void savebin(struct employee s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("employee.bin", "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(s[n]), n, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void retrievebin(struct employee s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("employee.bin", "rb");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fread(&s, sizeof(s[i]), n, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
int main(){

    savetext(st, c, 4);
    retrievetext(st, c, 4);
    printf("After reading text file");
    print(st, c, 4);

    savebin(st, 4);
    retrievebin(st, 4);
    printf("After reading bin file");
    print(st, c, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please only post images if and only if there is no other option. i.e. replace images with the text

Comment: That's the output. which is necessary for question

Comment: Can you not cut'n'paste the text to the question?

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: `length = (int)strlen(s[i].name); s[i].name[length - 1] = '\0';` This is totally meaningless and unnecessary. Just remove these lines.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I removed it but result is same

Comment: This is not the reason of the problem. First, where is `st` defined? Second, you have `fread` and `fwrite` in a loop. This makes no sense. These functions already have the size of the array as an argument. Third, `fwrite(&s...` and `fread(&s...` is *wrong*, you want `fwrite(s...` and `fread(s...`. And please [edit] your question and remove the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't get a warning here from this?

```c
fscanf(f, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", &c[i].grosspay, &c[i].fto, &c[i].sto, &c[i].np);
```

fscanf() will eat any float you throw at it, specifying the `%.2f` format like this doesn't really work.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

Try using it like this:

```c
fscanf(f, "%f %f %f %f\n", &c[i].grosspay, &c[i].fto, &c[i].sto, &c[i].np);
```

It was probably reading the file wrong, and then using the wrong line as an employee name.

PS: Your print() might have a small error:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // It should probably be i < n, instead of i < 4
```

And try to include an example input file, so people can test the code. At `main()`, there is no definition of `st`, so it's hard for people to see what's really happening if they can't test it themselves.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @RamiFar
`fscanf(f, "%f %f %f %f\n", &c[i].grosspay, &c[i].fto, &c[i].sto, &c[i].np);`
I edited my original answer to include it.